# How does "is:answer" work in search?

Tags: support, search

I expected this would return answers that contain my search term. However, it is returning answers from questions that contain the search term. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:answer%20thanks).

Comment: interesting. Compare to http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3A0+%2Bbody%3A%22thanks%22 which does what you want but is less intuitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want `is:answer body:thanks`.

Answer (score 4):

From my interpretation, what it does is that it only returns answers that satisfy the other search criteria you specify. `thanks` alone, for example, will search for questions that have "thanks" in either the question or its answers, and so you'll just get the answers to it. In that respect, it's not the most intuitive result when compared with how it works with other search terms (like `user:` or `votes:`, which search on a post-level).

Unless this gets changed, what you're *probably* looking for can be found using [a search for `is:answer body:thanks`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+body%3Athanks)